# Querying posts only if the current page is not paged?

Tags: query-posts, pagination, paged

For example, I want to query posts in a page. But I don't want to show them when the user clicks the pagination links.

Pretty much like what happens in Youtube. You only see the Top comments in the first page but when you click `Next` they disappear.

Any suggestions to accomplish this?

URL example:

Query the posts if it is the first page:

```
example.com/taiwantalk/forums/topic/technology-topic-11/
```

Don't query them if it is the second page or any other:

```
example.com/taiwantalk/forums/topic/technology-topic-11/page/2/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current page number is available in a global variable `$paged`.

```
if ( ! isset ( $GLOBALS['paged'] ) or ( $GLOBALS['paged'] < 2 ) )
{
    // run your code
}
```

Comment: why not just `$paged`?

Comment: @Ashfame That will not work if `register_globals` are `off` and the loop happens not in the global context.

Answer (score 2):

The same, with built-in function:

```
<?php if ( ! get_query_var('paged')) : ?>
    { your code here }
<?php endif; ?>
```